# Class-Array Interaction Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, class

I'm trying to set up a program to help me take care of grading for students in a class.  I've set it up to make a class of student then to read in from the file (something I'm not very familiar with in Ruby) via an array.  My programming experience is in java so if there are errors that can be explained by that I apologize.  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
class Student
  def initialize(str_LastName, str_FirstName, arr_Score)
    @str_LastName = str_LastName
    @str_FirstName = str_FirstName
    @arr_Score = arr_Score
    str_Grade = ""
    int_OutOf = 415
  end

  def get_LastName
    str_LastName
  end

  def get_FirstName
    str_FirstName
  end

  def get_Grade
    str_Grade
  end

  def set_TotalScore()
    sum = 0
    arr_Score.each do |item|
      sum += item
    end
    arr_Score[12] = sum
  end

  def set_Grade
    if arr_Score[12]/int_OutOf >= 0.9
      str_Grade = "A"
    elsif arr_Score[12]/int_OutOf >= 0.8
      str_Grade = "B"
    elsif arr_Score[12]/int_OutOf >= 0.7
      str_Grade = "C"
    elsif arr_Score[12]/int_OutOf >= 0.6
      str_Grade = "D"
    else
      str_Grade = "F"
    end
  end
end

def main
  file_name = "Grades"
  arr_students = Array.new(31)
  arr_scores = Array.new(12)
  int_i = 0
  file_io = open(file_name).readlines.each do |line|
    array = line.split(",").map(&:strip)
    student = Student.new(array[0],array[1],array[2..-2]) #the final element in the array is for the final score
    arr_students[int_i] = student
    puts "read #{arr_students[int_i]}"
  end
  file_name = "Graded"
  file_io = open(file_name,"a+")
  arr_students.each do |student|
    set_TotalScore
    set_Grade
    file.io_write(student)
    puts "write #{student}"
  end
end

main if __FILE__==$0
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, the Grades text file is formatted so that 1 student per line, with scores coming after the name, and I'm keeping the final array slot remaining 0 so that I can set it to the final score.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my run at it. I tried to stay true in general to the original intent of your code while introducing more Rubyish ways of doing things.

```
class Student
  def initialize(firstname, lastname, *scores)
    @firstname, @lastname, @scores = firstname, lastname, scores
  end

  def total_score
    @scores.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
  end

  def grade
    raise "TOO HIGH!" if total_score > MAX_SCORE

    case total_score / MAX_SCORE
    when 0.9..1.0;  "A"
    when 0.8...0.9; "B"
    when 0.7...0.8; "C"
    when 0.6...0.7; "D"
    else            "F"
    end
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@lastname}, #{@firstname}: #{total_score}, #{grade}"
  end
end

MAX_SCORE = 415.0
DATA.each_line do |line|
  arr = line.split(",").map(&:strip)
  student = Student.new *arr
  puts student
end

__END__
Herb,Goldberg,22,99,44,22,88,88
Mark,Sullivan,77,88,88,44,33
```

You can read and write to files like this(not tested):

```
outfile = File.open("Graded", "a+")
File.open("Grades").each_line do |line|
  ...
  outfile.puts student
end
outfile.close
```

Answer (score 0):

We can not easily reproduce your code because you open a file called "Grades" and we do not have or know of its content.

You should also add some code to first check whether your file exists, before continuing - right now your script exits with a Errno::ENOENT.

I would also suggest putting the logic in main into your class instead - let your class handle everything.

In the part:

```
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME

end
```

You can then simply initialize your class with a simple call such as:

```
Foobar.new(ARGV)
```

You described the "Grades" file but I did not understand what you wrote - it would be easier if you could link in to a sample, like via a pastie or gist, then link it in; and to also say what the part is that is not working, which is also unclear.

The style issues are secondary, I consider your code ok - the other poster here does not.

Comment: The format of the grading system would be similar to the following
**Smith, John, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6**... (numbers representing assignment scores)

Answer (score -2):

You should go through codecademy to get your ruby syntax down.

To access your initialized instance variables (@str_LastName (which should be @last_name), etc) you need to use "attr_reader :str_LastName", preferably at the top of the class. That'll definite you getter (setter is attr_writer, both is attr_accessor).

You can also do a sum on an array like this: [1,4,6,7].inject(:+).

Does Java not allow case statements? You should use that in set_grade. You also don't need to initialize str_Grade. In set grade, you could do @grade_letter ||= "A", and then calling set_grade will return that value on each call.

I didn't look through your main method. It's ugly though. Ruby methods probably shouldn't be more than 5 lines long.